# How to validate the date entered in XamDateTimeEditor using WPF/MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have the below XamDateTimeEditor box on one my WPF forms. I would like to validate(check if the date entered is valid or not).

```
   <igEditors:XamDateTimeEditor x:Name="xamDateTimeEditorDate"
                                     AutoFillDate="MonthAndYear"
                                     DropDownButtonDisplayMode="Always"
                                     Mask="mm/dd/yyyy"
                                     TabIndex="1"
                                     Text="{Binding Valid_Date,
                                                    Mode=TwoWay,
                                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,                                                         ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

Can someone share thoughts or your expertise on this?

Answer (score 0):

I usually bind to Value property to DateTime? on the ViewModel and then perform the check there